# Calculate IBAN account number

Tags: php

I have found this wiki page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBAN#Validating_the_IBAN

I followed the steps like this:

```
$iban = 'GB82WEST12345698765432';

$bankname      = substr($iban, 0, 4);
$accountnumber = substr($iban, 4);

$country = $this->convertToNumber($bankname);

$number = ($accountnumber . $country);
$area   = substr($number, 0, 4);

$accountnumber = substr($number, 4);

$number = $this->convertToNumber($area) . $accountnumber;

var_dump('3214282912345698765432161182');

var_dump($number);
```

so now I have the same number as in the example. output:

```
string 'GB82WEST12345698765432' (length=22)

string '3214282912345698765432161182' (length=28)

string '3214282912345698765432161182' (length=28)
```

If I do now `3214282912345698765432161182 mod 97 = 1`:

```
var_dump($number % 97);
```

I get : `int 78`

and they get as result `1`. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Probably php doesnot handle big integer. This is explain in the wiki. In python the result is 1. Googleing it seems http://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger could help ? By the way the wiki explain how to compute the modulo with langague that doesnot handle big integer.

Comment: After all I used the IBAN validate from symfony2: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Iban.html (>= Symfony2.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PHP badly handles the huge numbers.
All you need, is to store the number as arbitrary number and use proper PHP's functionality.
Please check the BCMath.
The example is clear:

```
php > var_dump(bcmod('3214282912345698765432161182',(int)97));
string(1) "1"
```

For the sake, you should pass the huge number as a string, so that PHP won't broke it, in this case, the result will be "1", if you would pass the huge number as int - it will become float prior to arriving to bcmod() and you will end up receiving "0" as a result.

Answer (score 2):

The wiki suggest an alogrithm for langague that doesnot support bignumber (it needs 220bits integer) :

1. Starting from the leftmost digit of D, construct a number using the first 9 digits and call it N.
2. Calculate N mod 97.
3. Construct a new 9-digit N by concatenating above result (step 2) with the next 7 digits of D. If there are fewer than 7 digits remaining in D but at least one, then construct a new N, which will have less than 9 digits, from the above result (step 2) followed by the remaining digits of D
4. Repeat steps 2–3 until all the digits of D have been processed

Coding this in php works give 1 as result

```
<?php
$iban = "3214282912345698765432161182";

$first = substr($iban, 0, 9);
$array = str_split(substr($iban, 9),7);

$result = $first % 97;
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $result = intval( strval($result) .  $value) % 97;
}

if ($result == 1) {
    echo "IBAN:$iban is valid";
} else {
    echo "IBAN:$iban invalid remainder:$result";
}

?>
```

Running test : http://ideone.com/1XNE2b

> IBAN:3214282912345698765432161182 is valid

Comment: How can I do such big number `/ 97`?

Comment: it seems bcdiv is a straight forward solution http://us3.php.net/manual/fr/function.bcdiv.php

Comment: -1: Not explaining how this is working (even if the algorithm is right). For non computer scientists: This is modular arithmetics also common in encryption.

Comment: @michi.0x5d I quote the algorithm detailed in the wiki that is implemented in this answer computing the modulo iteratively splitting the big number